# The first radio button's value is always being sent

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I have (4) radio buttons and submit button:

```
    <form class="addrecipe-form" method="GET">
    <div class="addrecipe-form-header-row">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" class="recipe-type-button" id="breakfast" name="recipe-type" value="breakfast" />
            <label for="breakfast" class="recipe-type-label">breakfast</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" class="recipe-type-button" id="appetizer" name="recipe-type" value="appetizer" />
            <label for="appetizer" class="recipe-type-label">appetizer</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" class="recipe-type-button" id="entree" name="recipe-type" value="entree" />
            <label for="entree" class="recipe-type-label">entree</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" class="recipe-type-button" id="dessert" name="recipe-type" value="dessert" />
            <label for="dessert" class="recipe-type-label">dessert</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="addrecipe-button" type="submit" name="recipe-submit"></button>
</form>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
var addRecipeForm = document.querySelector(".addrecipe-form");
var recipe_entry;

addRecipeForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    recipe_entry = {
        type : document.querySelector(".recipe-type-button").value)
    }
    console.log(recipe_entry.type)
```

I just can't figure out why I keep getting the first radio button's value instead of the one I'm clicking on.  Can someone enlighten me, pls?

Comment: `querySelector(".recipe-type-button")` returns the first matching element, not *the element you are thinking of* - computers don't work that way ... - perhaps `querySelector(".recipe-type-button:selected")` will work

Comment: document.querySelector("input[name=recipe-type]:checked").value might work.

Answer (score 0):

The "document.querySelector()" function returns the FIRST occurrence of that matching query selector.

I would use a for loop and "document.getElementsByClassName()" to check each radio button's value, and only save the state if it is selected.

Like this:

```
addRecipeForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("recipe-type-button").length){
        if(document.getElementsByClassName("recipe-type-button")[i].checked){
            recipe_entry = {
                type : document.getElementsByClassName("recipe-type-button")[i].value
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(recipe_entry.type)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
type: document.querySelector(".recipe-type-button:checked").value
```

.. to get the selected value.

Full script:

```
<html>
  <form class="addrecipe-form" method="GET">
    <div class="addrecipe-form-header-row">
      <div>
        <input
          type="radio"
          class="recipe-type-button"
          id="breakfast"
          name="recipe-type"
          value="breakfast"
        />
        <label for="breakfast" class="recipe-type-label">breakfast</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="radio"
          class="recipe-type-button"
          id="appetizer"
          name="recipe-type"
          value="appetizer"
        />
        <label for="appetizer" class="recipe-type-label">appetizer</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="radio"
          class="recipe-type-button"
          id="entree"
          name="recipe-type"
          value="entree"
        />
        <label for="entree" class="recipe-type-label">entree</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="radio"
          class="recipe-type-button"
          id="dessert"
          name="recipe-type"
          value="dessert"
        />
        <label for="dessert" class="recipe-type-label">dessert</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="addrecipe-button" type="submit" name="recipe-submit">
      Magic
    </button>
  </form>
  <script>
    var addRecipeForm = document.querySelector(".addrecipe-form");
    var recipe_entry;

    addRecipeForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      recipe_entry = {
        type: document.querySelector(".recipe-type-button:checked").value,
      };
      console.log(recipe_entry.type);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```